# I am getting error while uploading date data to firestore in flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

```
class User {
  String id;
  final DateTime birthday;

User(
      {this.id, required this.birthday,});

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        'birthday': birthday,
        'id' : id,
      };
```

My User model.

```
 final user = User(
                    birthday: DateTime.parse(_date.text),

 Future createUser(User user) async {
final docUser = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc();
user.id = docUser.id;

final json = user.toJson();
await docUser.set(json);
```

}

Where I am trying to save to Firestore.

```
DateTime? pickedDate = await showDatePicker(
                context: context,
                initialDate: DateTime.now(),
                firstDate: DateTime(1900),
                lastDate: DateTime.now());

            if (pickedDate != null) {
              setState(() {
                _date.text = DateFormat('dd-MM-yyyy').format(pickedDate);
              });
            }
```

The dateFormat form where I want the user's birthday.

When I press the save button to save it to the database,

**FormatException: Invalid date format
09-08-2012**

Gives a fault.

Answer (score 0):

Firebase uses `ISO8061` format to save dates. Let us say your b'day is 08-11-2004 so your code would be so

```
final date = DateTime(2004, 11, 8).toIso8601String();
```

Now you can upload the date variable into firebase as `Date` format.